# Extract a Cell/Td/tabledata value from a given row of a table using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

Here is my html table that is used in the Asp.net MVC razor view

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>

        <th class="col-md-2">
            Id
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-4">
            Description
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-3">
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-3">
            AssetType
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                @i.Id
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4">
                @i.Description
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3">
                @i.Count
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3">
                @i.AssetType
            </td>
            <td>
              <a onclick="getId()">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

My Js Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var getId = function () {
       //get current row 
       var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
       // get the id from the current row. or is there any better way ?         
    }   
</script>
```

Hi In the above code. all i want to do is when the user selects the edit link of the given row in the table. i want to extract id value of the selected row.

Could anyone please guide me in this one? I have seen articles that says how to get a given cell value from each row but didnt have any luck in finding articles that explains how to extract the data cell value from a given row.

Comment: `var id = currentRow.children('td').eq(0).text();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have it since you are generating the HTML from server side, when the user clicks pass the id to the funcion to do whatever you want with it.

```
 <td>
    <a onclick="getId('@i.Id')">Edit</a>
 </td>

function getId(id) {...}
```

or if you prefer you can use something like this:

```
 <a onclick="getId(this)">Edit</a>
        function getId(dom){
          var id = $(dom).parent().find('.col-md-2').html();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the id value to `data-id` attribute in the Edit link as below

```
<a data-id="@i.Id" class="edit-button" href="#">Edit</a>
```

Add the click event handler to the edit link, you can get the id value by using `$(this).data('id')`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.edit-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).data('id'));
    });
</script>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ds4t6jur/